# How to add partitions to a table with epoch hour in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I used to have data in daily partitions before,

```
'2014/01/01
 2014/01/02'
```

And i used to add partitions using,

```
'ALTER TABLE reporting_events_raw ADD PARTITION(year='2014', month='01', day='01')
 LOCATION 'path/folder/2014/01/01';'
```

and in create table statement we give

```
'PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string, day string)'
```

Now we will be having new partitions in an epoch hourly format, like

```
'folder/534800
 folder/534801
 folder/534802'
```

I am unable to figure out how to add partitions to the table.

Can anyone tell me how to add the partitions and also how to declare that partition type in create table statement.

Answer (score 0):

epoch time is nothing but a bigint value

> 'PARTITIONED BY (year string, month string, day string, epoch_hour bigint)'

You can use Dynamic Partitions in an insert overwrite query,

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE abc PARTITION ( year, month , day , epoch_hour )
select 
col1,
col2,
'2014' as year,
'01' as month,
'01' as day,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2014-01-01 00:00:00') as epoch_hour
from source_table;
```

Note that you need to derive the year,month,day also from your data which I have hard-coded above.
Let know if this helps you.